# IBM OS/400 - What is the risk of the object authority *ALL on user object?

Tags: privilege-escalation

During a review of an `IBM OS/400`, I noticed that some objects representing users had the object authority `*ALL` for the user `*PUBLIC`.

What is the risk of having an object representing a user with the object authority `*ALL` for the user `*PUBLIC` ? May any user **be able to have greater privileges** ? If yes, what modification he needs to do on the object to gain privileges?

Is there any simple recommendations you would recommend to prevent this?

Comment: I removed your question about the purpose of object-oriented design. It was not a security question.

Comment: This is looking like a product-specific configuration question, specifically, it looks like you are asking what `*ALL` really means.

Comment: Well, it's indeed a product-specific configuration question, but knowing what is an object user helps to understand how a privilege escalation might be possible. But I think the answer will include that part.